# Errors trying to run Maven inside a Docker container on a Windows 10 host

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to run a maven build inside a docker container on a Windows host. The build runs OK on OSX, but I've been struggling with file permissions & suchlike. I have it mapping volumes from %userprofile%.m2 on the host to /root/.m2 in the container. Initially it wasn't able to create the .m2 directory (permission denied) so I manually created that, & then it couldn't create the repository directory inside of that, so I created it manually, and now I'm getting this error message:

`C:\Users\matt.moran\myproject\dockerbuild>docker run -it -v C:\Users\matt.moran\myproject\dockerbuild/../:/usr/local/build/cdxwww:cached -v C:\Users\matt.moran/.m2:/root/.m2:cached --rm cdxbuild
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"/C/Users/matt.moran/.m2\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b42098a7e393129f5da0205ab6bedd94e87840fd1b8002445a9efb040b256fef/merged\\\" at \\\"/root/.m2\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/matt.moran/.m2: input/output error\\\"\"".`

What do I need to do to get this working? Is it a fundamental problem with the filesystem format, or is there some setting I can tweak?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this particular problem is due to Windows not liking forward slashes as a file separator - something of a gotcha when porting from OSX or *nix OSes.

I changed

`docker run -it -v C:\Users\matt.moran\myproject\dockerbuild/../:/usr/local/build/cdxwww:cached -v C:\Users\matt.moran/.m2:/root/.m2:cached --rm cdxbuild`

to

`docker run -it -v C:\Users\matt.moran\myproject\dockerbuild\..\:/usr/local/build/cdxwww:cached -v C:\Users\matt.moran\.m2:/root/.m2:cached --rm cdxbuild`

and this cured this particular error. Unfortunately I have other errors now but they're due to other causes.